# Из за чего округляется значения с плавающей запятой?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const double RENT = 3852.99; // константа, объявленная посредоством const

    printf("*%.2f*\n", RENT);
    printf("*%.1f*\n", RENT); // Почему окргуляется ?

}
```

В первом выводе функции printf значение не окуглуяется
Во втором выводе значение округляется .
Почему так ?

Comment: в первом не округляется, потому что нечему и некуда округляться. А какой вы ожидали вывод во втором случае?

Comment: 3852.9 вот так я ожидал

Comment: Я думал он вообще не округлится при .1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так должно работать согласно стандарту для этой функции:

> *A double argument representing a floating-point number is converted to decimal notation in the style [−]ddd.ddd, where the number of
> digits after the decimal-point character is equal to the precision
> specification. If the precision is missing, it is taken as 6; if the
> precision is zero and the # flag is not specified, no decimal-point
> character appears. If a decimal-point character appears, at least one
> digit appears before it. **The value is rounded to the appropriate
> number of digits.***

Т.е. в первом случае округления нет, т.к. количество цифр после запятой равно точности, а во втором есть, т.к. больше.

Comment: А что означает точность ? это то что после точки ?

Comment: @МихаилФленов да - "the number of digits after the decimal-point character is equal to the precision specification"